# How does ejb and JAX-RS play together?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, ejb

In my company we have a lot of code written for EJB.

Now we want change all the EJBs to a REST Service using JAX-RS namely Jersey.

So honestly I am pretty new to Java EE.

The old code uses a lot of Interceptors and  @EJB annotation.

So what I already found out. Somehow it was impossible to use Exception Interceptor in my Jax-RS code. Instead I had to use ExceptionMapper. So will any javax Interceptor work in my jax-rs Code ?? Or does jax-rs deliver its own interceptors ?

Comment: Your question is not that very clear. There are [general filters and interceptors](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html). There are the [ExceptionMappers](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6475) like you mentioned. There is also AOP support in some implementations. Not sure what else you are looking for. Try to rephrase your question for better help.

Comment: Which implementations support AOP ?

Comment: I know Jersey for sure via its DI system HK2. See [example](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-validate-return)